# O que fazer quando os votos parecem incoerentes com o conteúdo?

Tags: debate

Na pergunta [**Inserir os parágrafos de um arquivo JSON dentro de uma DIV**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/190/inserir-os-paragrafos-de-um-arquivo-json-dentro-de-uma-div) duas pessoas negativaram duas respostas (uma delas é minha).

O problema é que, a não ser que eu esteja completamente enganado, os votos foram dados com pressuposições erradas. Então a resposta com voto positivo estaria errada e as respostas que negativadas estariam certas.

Como vamos lidar com essas questões no br.SO?

Comment: As vezes isso vai acontecer. No teu caso o OP não entendeu a resposta e assumiu algo errado. Tentei explicar e coloquei um exemplo para ele. Se mesmo depois disso continuarem a dar downvote eu excluiria a resposta e guardaria uma solução criativa só pra mim mesmo.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

De uma maneira geral, você pode argumentar da melhor forma possível e tentar convencer as pessoas que participam da questão (o autor da perguntas os autores das respostas e outros que apenas estão comentando ou mesmo lendo e quem sabe votado) que você tem uma visão mais adequada da questão e que sua resposta é mais correta.

No começo pode ser um pouco mais difícil por termos pouco usuários, mas nem tanto porque temos usuários experientes.

A rede SE dá ferramentas fantásticas e uma filosofia básica para a comunidade funcionar da melhor forma possível, mas não provê maneiras para quem tudo seja 100% certo.

Você pode chamar a atenção do maior número de pessoas que entendem do assunto para ajudar. Na semana que vem poderá inclusive atrair novos usuários para contribuir positivamente.

A não ser que exista indicativo de fraude, além de tentar influenciar a comunidade para seguir o caminho correto, você só pode confiar e torcer que ela acerte a situação.

Note que você mesmo deixou a abertura, o que faz bem, de que você pode estar enganado. A comunidade irá decidir isso. Não digo que seja esse o caso, mas eu mesmo já tive certezas que depois me convenci que estava errado. Também já vi a comunidade determinar o caminho errado e pude fazer pouco. Ainda assim pude fazer alguma coisa e não consegui mudar a situação de alguma forma por falha minha. Claro que muitas vezes é difícil solucionar uma situação mas ainda assim se eu tenho tanta certeza da minha posição, é minha responsabilidade achar um caminho. Se alguém vê algo errado, a responsabilidade é dela mostrar que isso está errado.

Algumas vezes isso pode ser frustrante mas não consigo ver uma forma melhor de lidar com isso.

O que posso dizer é que não é função do moderador intervir nisso. Claro que o usuário que é moderador pode ajudar no que ele quiser e puder se ele domina o assunto, mas como um usuário comum. Ele pode comentar, votar, prover outra resposta mas não pode apagar uma resposta ou fechar uma pergunta por causa disso. Não faz parte da filosofia do SE determinar qual resposta é a correta, a comunidade deve fazer isso.

Você acha que pode ser fraude? Esse seria um caso para o moderador intervir. Um (flag/alerta/sinalizador) explicando o motivo poderia ser útil. mas a fraude precisa ficar evidente.

Estou tentando dar uma resposta geral e não específica para o exemplo que você citou. Acho que isso é mais útil nesse momento e mais adequada à pergunta como você formulou.

Comment: "Estou tentando dar uma resposta geral e não específica para o exemplo que você citou. Acho que isso é mais útil nesse momento e mais adequada à pergunta como você formulou." Eu acho que essa postura só acrescenta ao site! +1

Answer (score 0):

Sinceramente, alguém deveria editar aquela questão.

Ainda não sei se o autor pergunta qual a melhor forma de colocar parágrafos em HTML, ou se pergunta como fazer a substituição via Javascript.

**Cadê os editores?**
Não precisa ser moderador diamante como @gabe.
Pode ser você mesmo, é só clicar no botão **"editar"**.

Comment: Se você domina o assunto, pode editar também :) Claro que talvez a pergunta não tenha salvação. Tem casos que edição por terceiros não resolve.

Comment: Eu domino o suficiente, mas não sei o que fazer para não piorar a situação ali. Falei mais para incentivar o povo.

Comment: quanto a edição de perguntas alheias, uma vez uma pergunta minha foi editada para tirar o "hello" do início. Fiquei pensando se aquela edição foi realmente necessária... Sei que não tem nada a ver com a discussão atual do AP (Autor da Pergunta?), mas achei que valia a nota.

Answer (score 0):

Desculpe postar como resposta, mas tenho uma questão semelhante.
Eu estava quase abrindo nova pergunta aqui no meta mas resolvi pesquisar se não tinha algo similar. 
Esse tópico é o mais próximo que encontrei.

O caso que venho reportar é esse, onde um usuário comentou uma resposta minha e a negativou fazendo uma afirmação "meio errônea" pois não se adequa ao caso da pergunta.
[Verificar de onde veio o POST](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/56696/verificar-de-onde-veio-o-post/57075#57075)

Acredito que ele confundiu com o tema segurança de um modo geral ao invés do foco que é sobre spam.
Ele postou como se eu tivesse publicado a resposta como uma solução definitiva, e está bem claro no que comentei sobre não ser "a solução definitiva".

Na resposta do @bigown, aqui nesta página, entendi que devemos então ficar ali argumentando (trocando farpas de modo polido rsrs), para convencer opiniões de terceiros a favor ou contra, para então ganhar votos.. Ok, certo, bom argumento,.. rsrs...

Mas discordo disso porque o que ele comentou em si já "fere" uma das diretrizes, "uma resposta que carece de informações" e também fere uma das recomendações de evitar ficar rebatendo respostas alheias. Ao invés de ficar rebatendo, que poste então uma resposta provando os seus argumentos tal como eu fiz.

Eu discordo de alguns pontos da primeira resposta pois achei que escreveu demais e não diz nada com nada. Mas ao invés de negativar e afirmar que está errada, eu apenas postei outra resposta com ponto de vista e solução técnica diferente do que a maioria é acostumado.

Não quero dizer que a primeira resposta esteja errada. Não é isso. Mas apenas apresenta o óbvio e não chega a conclusão alguma.
Há muitos pontos a se considerar para criar um conjunto de medidas de segurança, por isso achei útil adicionar a resposta sobre o dns reverso, como se fosse um complemento a primeira resposta.

Há diversos outros pontos a se considerar e qualquer outra pessoa pode ir adicionando mais respostas, de preferência diferente dos temas que já foram abordados pois segurança é isso, é um conjunto de medidas pois não há nada 100% quando se fala de segurança.

Comment: Ou você pode não fazer nada e aceitar a situação que foi lhe imposta. O ideal é que elas não existissem, mas o mundo ideal não existe. Por sorte, sempre podemos ter opções do que fazer, claro que todas existentes podem não nos agradar, mas esta é a vida. Se você tiver uma ideia boa para evitar a situação quando alguém discorda da sua solução ela será muito apreciada. Eu só vejo duas possibilidades, abrir o debate, e foi o que você fez quando postou outra resposta, o que eu acho que fez bem, ou ficar quieto. Se alguém reclamar do que você postou, você pode defendê-la ou ficar quieto. Tem outra?

Comment: De acordo com os comentários dessa pergunta, o objetivo final é: "estou tentando proteger o flood/spam com um formulário". Resumindo, só entendi qual era o problema realmente, após ler os comentários da pergunta, porque ela é muito vaga. Normalmente uma pergunta vaga, recebe uma resposta vaga. **Sou a favor de editar a pergunta para deixá-la clara, ou pedir por informações adicionais nos comentários.** [A mesma posição que tinha em 2013.](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/79/64)

Comment: @MarcosZolnowski Você disse tudo, é só clicar no botão de "editar" ;)

Comment: Discordo dessa passividade perante casos assim. Entendo a questão do "argumentar" mas também tem a questão do "moderar", a qual é praticamente inexistente. Bom.. Deixa pra lá então. Bom saber como funcionam as coisas aqui. "take it easy".

Comment: Quanto a criticar a resposta dos outros, concordo que é falta de consideração. Mas ele tem o direito de discordar, desde que os argumentos tenham mérito. A crítica dele me fez analisar melhor a sua resposta. Estando ela certa, ou errada, posso dizer que foi interessante rever essa técnica. Não que a minha opinião tenha muito valor, mas digo que você é digno de respeito, por não levar isso para o lado pessoal.

Comment: No final, parece que eu disse: **Tudo bem eu ser um idiota, desde que tenha a razão.** Mas não é bem assim, as vezes nós queremos tanto fazer a coisa certa, que esquecemos das pessoas ao nosso redor. **Nós compreendemos, toleramos, mas tudo tem um limite.** Mas "praticamente inexistente" é um exagero, prefiro dizer, que os moderadores são bem moderados.

Comment: Sobre moderação inexistente, é sob o contexto do que estou comentando, não de um modo geral em todos os aspectos. Eu acho bem moderado mas quando se trata de assuntos desse tipo, são muito passivos e indiferentes.  Aliás, levei outro negativo lá... é disso que falo.. Um idiota vai lá negativa com um comentário chulo e vem outro e também negativa também.. vai na onda do outro.. mas enfim.. estou desencanado disso. E outras questões fora de foco, podemos discutir num momento mais apropriado para evitar bagunçar a questão dessa página.

Comment: Para esclarecer a questão da moderação, eu até gostaria de poder fazer mais. Porém, nós moderadores não temos acesso aos detalhes dos votos, não sabemos quem votou em quê. Só os gerentes de comunidade vêem isso. Então não posso agir sem dados que sustentem minha ação. E mesmo com os dados, eu só agiria se fosse um mesmo usuário votando em seus posts repetidamente – ou seja, votando na pessoa e não no conteúdo. Isso não pode. Mas votos contra "avulsos" aqui e ali fazem parte do jogo. Gostaria de saber exatamente o que você esperaria que os moderadores fizessem no caso dessa sua resposta.

Comment: deixa quieto, @bfavaretto. perda de tempo ficar lidando com espíritos de porco.. Mas só para deixar claro, o caso ali não se trata de opinião ou ponto de vista. Ambas as respostas ali estão corretas, a minha e a primeira. O problema é que provavelemnte os que votaram positivo na primeira resposta, ao ver a minha, votaram negativo na minha por não saber ler. Isso é um mal chamado analfabetismo funcional.. mas creio que seja "mais" que isso também. Deixa pra lá. Tenho minhas ocupações aqui e não tenho tempo para isso. Numa outra oportunidade , se tiver tempo podemos discutir.

Comment: @DanielOmine de fato tem muito espírito de porco no site mesmo, eu mesmo level dois negativos ontem sem motivo a não ser que as pessoas não gostam de mim. Eles devem ter seus motivos, não questiono, ninguém é obrigado a gostar de mim, eu sei que tenho personalidade forte, marco posição, e não costumo ter tanto cuidado c/ as palavras, esse ponto eu até entendo, só que acho injusto é descontarem nas coisas que eu posto. Não sei se é o mesmo caso mas tem muita gente que vota sem critério. Se não negativam, deixam de positivar, o no fim prejudica o *post* do mesmo jeito.

Comment: Esse tipo de coisa só dá para fazer uma coisa, reclamar para deixar claro o que está acontecendo, chamar a atenção. Algumas pessoas podem concordar com você, outras não o farão. Algumas vezes você estará certo mesmo, mas pode ser que alguma não seja o caso. E não garanto que todos negativos que eu recebi foram injustos. Pelo contrário, alguns foram justos, tanto que em alguns eu decidi remover o *post* (faço isto até mesmo quando não tenho negativos se eu achar que não está bom), em outros eu preferi manter pq ainda vi valor mesmo sabendo q tinha algum problema.